# According to Catholicism who was the Pope that immediately followed Peter?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, papacy

Do they supply a list of all the Popes from Peter onward? Or do they not claim to be able to trace the heritage of the papacy that far back?

Comment: Just google: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_popes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some catholic references on the succession of Popes:

[The List of Popes (Catholic Encyclopedia)](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12272b.htm): This says St Linus succeeded St Peter.

[List of popes (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_popes): This says St Linus succeeded St Peter.

[Popes of the Roman Catholic Church](https://www.catholic.org/pope/): This says St Linus succeeded St Peter.

The above list of lists include the official Catholic encyclopedia.

Comment: Linus, Cletus and Clement are also named in the Roman Canon (Eucharistic Prayer).